# How can I use morph transition without having an office 365 subscription?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

Why I don't see "morph transition" option in PowerPoint 2016?
I have updated it to the latest version of updates.
[image: my office version:]



[image: my transition list:]

How can I enable it without having an office 365 subscription? is it possible?

It seems disabled:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I enable it without having an office 365 subscription?

Unfortunately, you can't.

From [Using the Morph transition in PowerPoint](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Using-the-Morph-transition-in-PowerPoint-8dd1c7b2-b935-44f5-a74c-741d8d9244ea) (support.office.com):

> Note: This feature is only available if you have an Office 365 subscription.

Answer (score 1):

There is a backdoor to get morph in Desktop office without having an office 365 subscription.

1. Create or open your presentation in the [PowerPoint online](https://www.office.com/launch/powerpoint)
2. Apply the morph transition wherever you want
3. From the top ribbon in PowerPoint online, choose *Open in Desktop App*
4. Even though morph transition will not show up as available, it will work when you launch your presentation